# Oracle SQL - fetching a record at last

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT city from addr_tab
UNION ALL
SELECT 'zzzz' AS city from dual
)ORDER BY city
```

I am using the above approach to retrieve the 'zzzz' as last record of the table. But I don't think this would work all the time, as the city theoretically might be something  bigger than "zzzz" alphabetically. Is there any other robust approach to get this harcoded record as the last record?. I need this for reporting using oracle reports. Any help would be most welcome.

Comment: This is the kind of hack which has caused problems like the Y2K problem in the past. Don't do it! If that's not a real city, don't put this data in that table - move it somewhere else. Either to another table, maybe one specially constructed for this data, or even outside the database altogether. Or maybe city shouldn't be a column of this table.

Comment: @Robin Green: Thanks for commenting. I understand your concern. The city column was just used as an example. I am using this for reporting, as I stated in the question. Unfortunately, I don't have control over the data model, as it was created already by someone else. I wish I could do something(redesign the layout or something) in the reports, but what the hack, I might just use a quick and dirty solution for this. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as others have said (in comment and answer) there is probably a better way to approach the problem from the beginning; but if you need a temporary hack read on!...

Call the last record whatever you want...
'zzzz' is fine...
and then use a custom `ORDER BY` like:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM (
       SELECT city 
         FROM addr_tab
       UNION ALL
       SELECT 'zzzz' AS city 
         FROM dual
       )
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN city = 'zzzz' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
    city;
```

Comment: Thanks Adam Bernier. This might just work for the current task.

Answer (score 4):

Add another virtual column (order_col) to use for ordering.
The query would end up something as follows.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT city, 1 as order_col from addr_tab
UNION ALL
SELECT 'zzzz', 2 as order_col AS city from dual
)ORDER BY order_col, city
```

THis way you can guarantee that 'zzzz' will always be last since the primary ordering column (order_col) is guaranteed to have a lower value for 'zzzz' than for all the rest of the records.

Answer (score 0):

this can be solve by following query also

```
 SELECT * FROM 
 ( SELECT city from addr_tab order by city)
   UNION ALL 
  SELECT 'zzzz' from dual;
```

now got one more style to do this

```
with 
b1 as 
(
SELECT city from addr_tab order by city
)
select city from b1
union all 
SELECT 'zzzz' from dual;
```

so any one you can use ....